# Creating new activity when clicking on listView Item

Tags: android, listview

I am new to android developing and i got a few troubles there.I made a list of items in ListView, so i want to generate a new activity based on which item was clicked. In the first class as you can see i want to open an activity with imageView with AKM texture which is already in drawable. When click on m416, i want to generetare an activity with imageView and m416 texture which is also in drawable and same with other items. I look for any help there, i will be greatful for anything.
P.S. sorry for english.

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Weaponry extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int EXTRA_KEY_COUNT = R.drawable.akm;

ListView listView; 
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weaponry);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ivMain);
     final String[] values = new String[] {"AKM", "M416", "Scar-L", "GROZA", "UMP", "UZI",
            "AWM", "M-14", "M24", "Colt 1911", "Glock-19"};

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Weaponry.this, WeaponDetails.class);

                intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(EXTRA_KEY_COUNT), values[position]);

                startActivity(intent);

            } else if (position == 1) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Weaponry.this, WeaponDetails.class);
                intent1.putExtra("R.drawable.m416", values[position]);

                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        }
    });

    }
}</i>
```

"Future generated activity"

```
public class WeaponDetails extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_weapon_details);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource();

}


}
```

and if needed xml code for second acitivity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.drews.projnumba.WeaponDetails">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="248dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

in case of something there is xml code for the first activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/weapon_types">
</TextView>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/ivMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can store the image drawable like

```
final int[] imageResources = new int[] {R.drawable.AKM, R.drawable.M416, R.drawable.UMP};
```

then you can pass the image resource id with the intent

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Weaponry.this, WeaponDetails.class).putExtra("image", imageResources[position]));
        }
    });
```

Then in the WeaponDetails.class you can fetch the image resource and set the imageView using

```
int image = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("image");
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setImageResource(image);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Weaponry.this, WeaponDetails.class);
```

With:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), WeaponDetails.class);
```

and:

```
startActivity(intent);
```

with:

```
getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tu put the value inside the extras

```
intent1.putExtra("name", values[position]); 
intent1.putExtra("image_resource",
R.drawable.m416);
```

Then use this on your new activity:

```
int imageResource = getIntent().getIntExtra("image_resource");
```

Answer (score 0):

You just Copy And Paste this code..

```
 final ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ivMain);
        final String[] values = new String[] {"AKM", "M416", "Scar-L", "GROZA", "UMP", "UZI",
                "AWM", "M-14", "M24", "Colt 1911", "Glock-19"};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1, values);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selectedFromList = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                switch (position){
                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("name",selectedFromList);
                        Log.d("name",selectedFromList);
                        intent.putExtra("pos",position);
                        intent.putExtra("image_resource",EXTRA_KEY_COUNT);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    //
                    default:break;
                }

            }
        });
```